# List of numbers until n divisible by A or B but not divisible by C

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I have three integers: A, B, C

I want to print all integers from 1 to range which are divisible by A or B but not by C.

My code

```
for($n=0; $n < $range; $n++){
   if(($n < $a && $n < $b) || ($n % $c == 0)){
     return [];
   }
   if(($n % $a == 0 || $n % $b == 0) && ($n % $c > 0)){
     $outputArr[] = $n; 
   }
}
```

Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You show a fantasy code that produces syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

You can speed this up but it is more complicated, especially if you must print these out in order. Here is a method that doesn't print them out in order.

First write a [greatest common divisor (gcd) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) in PHP, and then write a [least common multiple (lcm) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Least_common_multiple) that uses the gcd function. Compute m = lcm(a, b). Iterate over *multiples* of a and print them out if they are not divisible by c. Next, iterate over multiples of b and print them out if they are not divisible by m or c.

Other optimizations along these lines are possible. For example, you can precompute the multiples of a or b that are not multiples of m and store them in an array. This works if m is not too large, division is more expensive than array access in PHP, and range is significantly larger than m.

Comment: You can calculate m = lcm(a, b, c), store all numbers < m that fullfill the conditions in an array, then you go through multiples of m and just print the values in the array with offset, e.g. a = 3, b = 4, c = 6: => m = 12, array = [3, 4, 8, 9], then you start with 0 and just print the array, then you go to 12 and print 12 + array values, then you go to 24 and print 24 + array values and so on.

Comment: @maraca: Yes, that is even better, I like that.

Answer (score 1):

PHP version 7 or higher is so fast when only integer operations are used that micro-optimizations are no longer needed.

```
$res = [];
$a = 9;
$b = 13;
$c = 26;
$range = 10000;

for($n=$a; $n <= $range; $n += $a){
  if($n%$c != 0) $res[] = $n;
}
for($n=$b; $n <= $range; $n += $b){
  if($n%$c != 0) $res[] = $n;
}

$res = array_unique($res);
sort($res);
```

This example takes about 1 millisecond to calculate the 1411 values on my 8-year-old system. This time for the presentation of the result is several times greater.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more optimized solution, that also works efficient when `a` and `b` are large. You can simply run through the multiples of `a` and `b`:

```
for($na=$a, $nb=$b; $na <= $range || $nb <= $range;  ){
   if ($na <= $nb) {
      if ($na % $c != 0)
         $outputArr[] = $na; 
      if ($na == $nb)
         $nb += $b;
      $na += $a;
   } else {
      if ($nb % $c != 0)
         $outputArr[] = $nb; 
      $nb += $b;
   }
}
```

Each output number is only generated once, and already in the desired order.

If you are afraid the modulo test is slow, you could also have a `next multiple of c` running along, but that looks like too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `range()` and `array_filter()`.

```
$range = 20;
$A = 2;
$B = 3;
$C = 9;

$nums = array_filter(range(1, $range), function ($x) use ($A, $B, $C) {
    return (!($x % $A) || !($x % $B)) && $x % $C;
});

var_dump($nums);
```